# Flutter: Form validation validates all textfields together

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to validate the login form which has an email and password field. Validation mode is set as `onUserInteraction`.

But the behavior currently, validates the password field even when start typing on the email field.
[image].
What I am trying to achieve is

1. Validate individual text fields. not all together
2. Maybe, validate only after focus out (On blur)

   ```
   Form(
     autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
     onChanged: () {
       controller.isValidForm.value =
           controller.formKey.currentState.validate();
     },
     key: controller.formKey,
     child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         FormTextField(
           validator: (value) {
             if (value.isEmpty) {
               return 'Please enter an email address';
             } else if (!controller.emailRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
               return 'Invalid email address!';
             }
             return null;
           },
           onSaved: (value) {
             controller.model.emailAddress = value;
           },
           title: "Email id",
         ),
         UIHelper.verticalSpaceLarge(),
         FormTextField(
           isObscure: controller.isPasswordObsecured.value,
           validator: (value) {
             if (value.isEmpty) {
               return 'Please enter a password';
             }
             return null;
           },
           onSaved: (value) {
             controller.model.password = value;
           },
           title: "Password",
           isObscureCallBack: controller.changePasswordVisibility,
           isPasswordField: true,
         ),
         UIHelper.verticalSpaceExtraLarge(),
         FormSubmitButton(
           isValidForm: controller.isValidForm.value,
           onPressed: () {
             if (controller.formKey.currentState.validate()) {
               controller.formKey.currentState.save();
               print(controller.model);
               controller.doLogin();
             }
           },
           label: "Login",
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ),
   ```

Comment: this is because you are using onChanged on Form.

Comment: Try removing `onChanged: () {
    controller.isValidForm.value =
        controller.formKey.currentState.validate();
  },`

Comment: if you want to continue using this style, then you will have to make 2 different keys.

Comment: removing onChange has no effect on the validation behaviour @UjjwalRaijada

Comment: validator only works when it is called. And it is being called on onChange and on FormSubmitButton. Please try to remove onChange and use hot reload. It should work/

Comment: How do I use isValid method on form ? as mentioned - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/48948 I tried  onChanged: () {
              controller.isValidForm.value =
                  controller.formKey.currentState.isValid();
            },

it says method is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You should put the `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` inside `FormTextField`, not inside the `Form` to enable individual text field validation on user interaction (change/blur)

```
Form(
  //not here
  //autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  onChanged: () {
    controller.isValidForm.value =
        controller.formKey.currentState.validate();
  },
  key: controller.formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      FormTextField(
        // put it here
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        ...
        title: "Email id",
      ),
      UIHelper.verticalSpaceLarge(),
      FormTextField(
        // and put it here
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        ...
        title: "Password",
      ),
      ...
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from our conversation ... what I do is, I create a function which is called when the form is submitted. That is the time validations are checked and error is shown if there is any.
My code to validate:

```
void _submit() async {
  final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();   // validation
  if (!isValid) {     // if validation is false it will return error as per mentioned by you in validator
    return;
  }
  _form.currentState!.save();      // if everything is fine, it will save the form and proceed further

  // code from here if the form gets validated

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the same "controller" on all the TextFormFields. Try changing the controllers to be unique per TextFormField.